# String value = 4.30000000e+01 how to parseInt?

Tags: java, integer, double, string-parsing

```
String value = 4.30000000e+01;
```

how to parseInt??
in java

I already tried using parseInt(value, 10)..
in fact, javascript parseInt can convert but java method cause error

how can i solve?

Comment: General advice: if you get an error and ask about it you should tell us _which_ error your get (along with as many details as possible, e.g. the actual portion of your code that caused the error).

Comment: Thanks Thomas:) I'll keep in mind your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integers are not supposed to be represented like this. Eventually, you can parse it as a BigDecimal then take its int value :

```
int i = new BigDecimal("4.30000000e+01").intValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

you have a string, you can parse it into a double object and invoke the method **intValue()**

```
int r = Double.valueOf("4.30000000e+01").intValue();
System.out.println(r);
```

Answer (score 0):

`e+01` means exponent. so `e+01` is actually `10 pow 1`. `Double` can parse that:

```
Double.valueOf("4.30000000e+01") // 43.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Reference JLS Section 3.10.2 ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2 ) : the decimal part of Floating point literals can be expressed in the form of scientific notation e.g e+01 as in your example.

```
Double d = Double.parseDouble(value);
```

will return double value, which you can cast to int (with loss of precision) if you want integer output.